# Pass value from Android Studio to unity?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, text-recognition, android-unity-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I am doing a Text recognition project by using android studio and google vision like this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmuz8qIWcL8&t=702s. But I need to pass the recognized text to Unity in order to display the 3D Model and some information related to the recognized text. Then, user can view and rotate that 3D model.
The question is any suggestion or method can be use to pass the string or text or value from android studio to unity ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple http server to your unity project and listen for commands.  You can have android studio issue http get or post requests, and you can parse the request in your unity app to do whatever you want.

Not only can you then process input from any source, you can respond with output as well.